# I obfuscated my commercial software, i lost source

Tags: php, obfuscation

I obfuscated my web software with srcProtector and I archived files, I uploaded a new version of the software on the website.

The problem is I forgot to copy files in a new path for backup.
**VERY VERY BAD!**

Code looks like:
[image: obfuscated file]

I tried already unPHP.

(is there any winscp undo button (reconnect session) or any deobfuscator for this?)

Comment: You really don't have any backups of your source code? Do you use git or svn or some other revision control system? If so, you can use git/svn to revert to previous version of the source code.

Comment: I had a backup in winscp on principal website (replaced files with OBFUSCATED new version) AND ON PC (FORGOT to backup)

Comment: Do you use git or svn for source code revision control?

Comment: no.............

Comment: Looks like you might be out of luck. Maybe try contacting the developers of srcProtector. http://phpobfuscator.net/contacts.html

Comment: You're in luck: you used snake oil garbage to obfuscate your code, so you should be able to get a minified version back with only a few minutes' effort.

Comment: Please do not destroy your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you've learned a valuable lesson about the importance of source control, and backups in general. I'm sorry it happened this way.

Obfuscators are just speed bumps. The only info that is actually lost is stuff like comments; everything else is just made hard to read. For example, all your strings got base64 encoded, which is trivial to reverse. The names of those string variables/constants appear to themselves have been encoded and stored in a lookup table; you should be able to reverse that too. Some names that were internally-scoped only are probably lost, but you should be able to figure them out from context and memory.

There may exist tools to automate some of the above steps. Alternatively, you might have to write one. A relatively short python script could recover all the `$GLOBALS` assignments in your screenshot, for example (you could do it in any language, python is just a convenient balance of power and ease-of-use). Assuming the obfuscator did anything worse than just hide the names of stuff, you might have to do some actual work picking apart the logic in the obfuscated functions, but unless you're implementing anything super complicated (advanced math, handling binary data formats, etc.) it should be pretty easy.

---

Technically off-topic and just out of curiosity, why are you obfuscating PHP source? If you're just uploading it to your own server, all you're doing is wasting CPU cycles. If you distribute the source to third parties (such as customers), I suppose you could say some obfuscation makes sense, but generally you just solve that with copyright law unless your software actually contains genuine trade secrets that others don't know how to do and would find worth the effort of reading your code to figure out. If that's the case, then obfuscation is "better" than nothing, but - as mentioned at the top - it's just a speedbump.

Also, especially if you aren't using source control, you shouldn't be obfuscating files in place. Create a new destination path for the modified files, don't overwrite the originals.